# Not displaying editor in Firefox 3.6.13, Ubuntu 10.04 (Stack Overflow only)

Tags: support, editor

I tried clearing my cache, cookies, and everything like reloading my page. Killing my Mozilla process, but still it's not displaying only for Stack Overflow.

Here is the screenshot.

[image]

**EDIT**:--

Every other site is working perfectly (I posted this question on Meta Stack Overflow using the same browser). I am getting issues only in case of Stack Overflow. And more over, last night it was working for Stack Overflow.

**EDIT**

I use the [web developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60/) tool-bar to check JavaScript errors, and these are the two errors I get while loading the Stack Overflow ask question page.

Here is the screen-shot. Check pop up error messages. (Two in number)

[image]

Comment: What if you enable JavaScript and disable AdBlock?

Comment: @TimeMachine.. Every other site is working perfectly (i posted this question on meta using same browser.). I am getting issues only in case of stackoverflow. and more over last night it was working.

Comment: Strange… Does Firebug tell you anything you can post here? Some error message, or a warning?

Comment: No repro on Firefox 3.6 in Ubuntu 10.10

Comment: Min is firefox 3.6.13..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what solved the issue.

I updated my Ubuntu, and it's working perfectly now.

My Mozilla version is still the same. Any idea?

Comment: Probable needed to clear your cache.  This happens to me sometimes.